# Mixing PHP with XML

Tags: php, xml

I wonder if it's possible to mix XML with php. and i'll explain what I exactly mean:

Is it possible to mix between xml file (with the `<?xml ... ?>` prologue), and `<?php ... ?>` script? For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<tag<?php if(isset($_GET['tag_attribute']) && !empty($_GET['tag_attribute'])) { echo ' ' . $_GET['tag_attribute']; } ?>>
</tag>
```

And in case something like this can be done, does it need to be created through `php`? perhaps I can create regular `xml` file and change its extension to `.php`?

thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It seems like i've found out that it is possible and how. all I needed to do is to create regular XML file with php extension and this `php` line above:

`<?php header('Content-type: application/xml'); ?>`